# Способ отправки данных с сервера node js в модальное окно

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

На сервере, который написан на node js, имеются данные типа string. Как это можно отправить в содержимое модального окна? Содержимое окна:

```
.modal-overlay
            .modal
                a.close-modal
                  svg(viewbox='0 0 20 20')
          
                .modal-content
                    h3  something here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать Server Side Events, либо Websoket. На клиенте уже обработать и поместить в модальное окно